# Identifying cities from shapefile that showcases functional urban areas (FUA) of Germany

Tags: qgis, shapefile, germany

How do I identify which FUAs do certain cities belong to (ex. which FUA does Worms belong to) from the FUA shapefile I have (see image)?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @JayaJain! Try using a spatial join tool like `Join attributes by location`.